# Is it possible to custom size the fabric twitter login button?

Tags: swift, twitter, authentication, uibutton, twitter-fabric

Supposedly, the twitter login button is a subclass of UIButton but none of the methods associated with setting a `UIButton`(such as `setTitle()`, `setBackgroundColor()` etc) object seem to work with the `twitter` button. Specifically, I'm trying to resize it but nothing seems to work. Here's what I've tried so far in my `viewDidLoad()`

```
let twitterLoginButton = TWTRLogInButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50))
self.view.addSubview(twitterLoginButton)
```

I also tried this

```
let twitterLoginButton = TWTRLogInButton.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50))
self.view.addSubview(twitterLoginButton)
```

Then I tried to create a container UIView for the login button with the above rect parameters and then place the button into it, instead of directly in the UIView controller like so

```
let twitterLoginButton = TWTRLogInButton()
let twitterLoginButtonParent = TWTRLogInButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50))
twitterLoginButtonParent.addSubview(twitterLoginButton)
self.view.addSubview(twitterLoginButtonParent)

let twitterLoginButtonSize = CGSize(width: 200, height: 50)
twitterLoginButton.sizeThatFits(twitterLoginButtonSize)
```

At least this time, the button doesn't get stuck in the top left hand corner but is forced to assume the x and y positions of its new parent. However it still cant be forced to assume the size of its parent as I intended. 
Is there any way the button can be forced to resize?  With the facebook button, it's much easier.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it. Apparently I had to first initialize the button with loginCompletion

```
    let twitterLoginButton = TWTRLogInButton(logInCompletion: { session, error in
        if (session != nil) {
            print("signed in as \(session!.userName)");
        } else {
            print("error: \(error!.localizedDescription)");
        }
    })

    twitterLoginButton.frame  = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 50)
```